# What is causing the PHP strtolower UTF-8 failure

Tags: php, mongodb, utf-8

The answer to the following problem would be to use mb_strtolower().  however what I would like to know is what is causing the following problem:

I have an application which converts a user given string to lowercase using strtolower() and attempts to insert it in MongoDB. When I insert a special character like: ö it works just fine locally. But remotely on a different server it fails stating:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'non-utf8 string: \xe3\xb6'

I checked all the mb_* settings, I checked the locales. I can't figure out why it works locally but fails online.

edit: added strtolower

Comment: Exact string causing the problem would definitely help. Otherwise it is known that some string sent to Mongo contains non-utf8 characters (byte sequences). How do you create initial utf-8 string?

Comment: Hi the string is any string with ö in it fails remotely but not locally. It's a webapplication for that matter.

Comment: Well, watch the chain: (you get data somewhere) -> (you concieve data as **valid** utf-8 string) -> (you put it into Mongo) -> (Mongo complains that string is not valid utf-8). This means that somewhere in the chain you treat your data as valid utf-8, but it's not. Not every byte sequence is a valid utf-8.

Comment: Yes, strtolower() is causing the problem and mb_strtolower would be a sufficient fix or removing strtolower would work too. but I would like to know why this happends on the remote server and not on my localhost. The settings are basically identical except for the fact that I run Ubuntu and the server runs Cent OS. What is causing strtolower to output invalid utf-8.

Comment: _“What is causing strtolower to output invalid utf-8”_ – given the same input data, it should always generate the same (broken) output. Check that, by making a debug output on both systems – send it through `urlencode` or something, so that you can see the actual byte values in your result string. If those are the same for both systems, then it’s an issue with your database settings or something.

Comment: the input data before the strtolower() takes place is:

%C3%B6

After the strtolower:

%E3%B6

Perhaps it's wise to mention that array_map('strtolower') is used. Not sure if that matters.